# How to find the number of received event record count when using the filter strategy?

Tags: spring-kafka

EDIT : I would like to find the no. of records that rejected from filter in one poll of batch.

For example : In one poll, let say if 1000 records got consumed from a partition, among them 500 records got eliminated through filter strategy and finally remaining 500 records will be reached to listener for the processing.

Right now the the issue is, I am able to see only the records count that received at listener, but not able to see the total no. of messages that got eliminated. Basically, I would like to get the count of elimination in one poll of the batch or total count received at filter.

### Listener:

```
public class MyConsumer {

    @Autowired
    private TestEventProcessor testEventProcessor;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${input.topic}", containerFactory = "testBatchListenerContainerFactory")
    public void onMessage(
            @Payload List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> consumerRecords, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        log.info("Total no of records in this batch :" + consumerRecords.size());
        testEventProcessor.processAndAcknowledgeBatchMessages(consumerRecords, acknowledgment);
    }

}
```

### Kakfa Config:

```
 @Bean
     public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> batchListenerContainerFactory() {
        
                ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        
                factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory(CGID));
                factory.setConcurrency(10);
                factory.setBatchListener(true);
                factory.setAckDiscarded(true);
                int counter = 0;
factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
                
                factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(
                        (consumerRecord) -> {

                            try {
                                counter++;
                                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                if (hasRequiredFields(consumerRecord)) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                log.error("exception occured:",
                                        consumerRecord.value(),
                                        consumerRecord.partition(),
                                        consumerRecord.offset(),
                                        ex.getStackTrace());
                                return true;
                            }
                            return true;
                        });
            }
```

I have some filter criteria as part of the hasRequiredFields()
which does the records elimination. Though I am setting the batch of records to consume, I always see that very little count from the listener side. I would like to know how many records are being received, how many records are getting excluded, and how many records are getting processed?

Comment: I must be missing something in your question - why can't you just update counters in your filter?

Comment: @Gary,  I have updated the question.. can you help on it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in mechanism for a record listener to get the number of records in the batch of records returned by the poll.

One solution would be to implement `ConsumerInterceptor` and add it to the consumer configuration.

Then, `onConsume(ConsumerRecords)` will be called for each batch (before the first record is sent to the listener) and you can get the `count()` there.

If you have only one listener with concurrency=1, you could store the count in a static field. Otherwise you would need to use a static `ConcurrentMap` with the thread name as the key and the count in the value.

Probably simplest to implement `ConsumerInterceptor` on your filter.

Comment: Thanks @Gary!! Appreciate your inputs